# update a value in config.json in python

Tags: python, json, tkinter

I am trying to use a tkinter button to update a value in config.json file with the key in dictionart as "TOKEN".

```
with open("game\\config.json") as f:
    config=json.load(f)
acctoken1field.insert(0,config.get("TOKEN"))
def replacetoken(finaltoken):
    config["TOKEN"]=finaltoken
acctoken1submit=Button(frame3,text='submit',command=lambda: replacetoken(acctoken1field))
```

i have tried the dump method but it just doesnt works i fail to understand why. Can someone please help me suggest some methods with it:)

The config.json file looks like this:-

```
{"TOKEN": "help","SUPPORT_TOKEN": "namess" , "LATENCY": "1", "NOTE": "y = on | n = off "}
```

Comment: where exactly did you `dump` ?

Comment: could you provide the config.json? (at least the relevant part)

Comment: @VikasP in detail i have a field acctoken1field where i am inserting the already present value of "TOKEN" in config.json. The user can edit that field and then click the submit button to update the values in config.json

Comment: @Tranbi please check the edited part i added the config

Comment: So "help" will be automatically written in your field `acctoken1field`, then you change the text in this field, click "submit" and nothing happens? At this point only your `config` variable has been changed. You have to add the dump in `replacetoken()'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, "help" will be automatically written in your field `acctoken1field`, then you change the text in this field, click "submit" and nothing happens? At this point only your config variable has been changed. You have to add the dump in `replacetoken()`:

```
with open("game\\config.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(config, f)
```

Comment: so basically we use json.load to store the config then we edit the config and then dump it back to the file so its a three step process right?